# Multiprocessing.pool(): slower than the sequential

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to solve a derivative by finite elements using python (and Numpy). When I solve sequentially no problem, but the for is very large and takes too long. Then, I try to implement `multiprocessing` with share memory, but I have some questions. I run the above code in a machine with 4 cores. The code abode run well, but  much slower that sequential code, Why? I'm not doing well?

```
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
n = 40  #array size 
deriv2_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, n)
temp_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, n)
deriv2 = np.ctypeslib.as_array(deriv2_base.get_obj())
temp = np.ctypeslib.as_array(temp_base.get_obj())

temp[-1] = const['T0']

def calculo(i, def_param=(deriv2, temp)):
    pos_ini = i*blockDim + 1/(1 + i)
    pos_fin = (i + 1)*blockDim - (i+1)/cores

    deriv2[pos_ini:pos_fin] = (temp[pos_ini-1:pos_fin-1] -2*temp[pos_ini:pos_fin] +   temp[pos_ini+1:pos_fin+1]) / delta_z**2
    temp[pos_ini:pos_fin] = temp[pos_ini:pos_fin] + kappa*deriv2[pos_ini:pos_fin] *    delta_t_seg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = cores)
    for j in xrange(i_steps):
        pool.map(calculo, range(cores))
    print temp
```

Tanks!

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or something later? `1/(1 + i)` is 0 in python 2.6 and 2.7 but 0.33333 in python 3+.

Comment: the `i` argument to `calculo` is a `range`? It looks like you are treating it as an integer.

Comment: "...is 0 in python 2.6 and 2.7 but a rational from 0 to 1 in python 3+ (assuming `i` is non-negative)."

Comment: I use python 2.7, but in my fist line of code I use `from __future__ import division` and this is the ERROR!! tanks!!